# Trouble with understanding how TensorFlow receives and processes data

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I have recently begun studying Deep Learning and am confident of my understanding of both the theory and the in-depth practical implementations of RNNs and LSTMs. I have written a very simple RNN which learns to add together two binary numbers, using only numpy. I am now trying to become familiar with the TensorFlow API so that I no longer have to build my models from scratch.

Despite my confidence in my understanding of NNs and in my programming ability, I am becoming very frustrated as I keep hitting walls when it comes to understanding the high-level that TensorFlow abstracts the models, and how data to be used should be structured. An example of a wall I have hit is in the code below, where I am attempting to implement a simple RNN that takes in a list of lists/sequences of integers, and will then learn how to classify a single sequence as either increasing or decreasing. `generate_data()` outputs two lists:

- `data` is in the form on `[[1, 2, 3], [9, 8, 7]]` and is the input sequences.
- `labels` is a list of either `1`s or `0`s - a 1 meaning the corresponding sequence is increasing, and a 0 for decreasing.

`x` is the placeholder for the input sequences and `y` is the placeholder for the corresponding labels. My thought process is for each input sequence to be received by the RNN as `x`, a single column tensor with each row being a single integer of the sequence - a single time step in the unrolled RNN. The RNN will then output a single integr (`0` or `1`) after each full forward propogation of the RNN (after one entire `x` tensor has been processed.

I am getting an error that on the last line that inputs must be a sequence. I am failing to understand how this single column tensor is not considered a sequence, and how it needs to be shaped in order for it to be a sequence.

As a side note, the next biggest misunderstanding I have is that in all the theoretical explanations I have read of RNNs, there are 3 weighted matrices - one from input to hidden state, one from hidden state to output, and one between the hidden states of each time step. All coded examples I have seen using TensorFlow only seem to have a single weighted matrix. How is this so? How does TensorFlow use this single matrix as an abstraction of the 3 deep levels ones? And am I shaping this matrix correctly in the line `W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([sequence_len, output_dim]))`?

```
from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import rnn
import random

sequence_len = 5        # Input Dimension
max_num = 1000          # Must be >= than (sequence_len - 1)
output_dim = 1
hidden_dim = 16
batch_size = 1000

def generate_data(sample_size, seq_len=sequence_len, max = max_num):
    data = []
    labels = []
    for _ in range(sample_size):
        type = (1 if random.random() < 0.5 else 0)
        temp = []
        if type == 1:
            labels.append(1)
            temp.append(random.randint(0, max_num - seq_len + 1))
            for i in range(1, seq_len):
                temp.append(random.randint(temp[i - 1] + 1, max_num - seq_len + i + 1))
            data.append(temp)
        if type == 0:
            labels.append(0)
            temp.append(random.randint(0 + seq_len - 1, max_num))
            for i in range(1, seq_len):
                temp.append(random.randint( 0 + seq_len - i - 1, temp[i - 1] - 1))
            data.append(temp)
    return data, labels

input_data, labels = generate_data(100000)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, sequence_len])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, output_dim])

W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([sequence_len, output_dim]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([output_dim]))

cell = rnn.BasicRNNCell(hidden_dim)
outputs, states = tf.nn.static_rnn(cell, x, dtype=tf.int32)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.static_rnn` expects a list of `Tensors` as per [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/static_rnn) so it can determines the length of your RNN (note that this must be determined before runtime and this is why you need to pass a python list of `Tensors` and not a `Tensor`):

> **inputs:** A length T list of inputs, each a Tensor of shape [batch_size, input_size], or a nested tuple of such elements.

`outputs, states = tf.nn.static_rnn(cell, [x], dtype=tf.int32)` should work.

Regarding your side question, part of the answer can be found in the [implementation of `BasicRNNCell`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py):

```
def call(self, inputs, state):
    """Most basic RNN: output = new_state = act(W * input + U * state + B)."""
    output = self._activation(_linear([inputs, state], self._num_units, True))
    return output, output
```

but it really depends on the `RNNCell` you choose to use. This is the part of your model which will implements the `input` to `state`, the `state` to `state` and the `state` to `output` logics.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be working. I will continue on with my RNN and let you know if I have any other problems or misunderstandings.

Comment: I managed to get my NN _working_ today, but I did so by analysing the code of a very different toy example to mine, and implementing similar practices as best as I saw fitting. Unfortunately, my model is not learning at all. It's accuracy is fluctuating completely randomly. As I said, I am new to TensorFlow and cannot understand why it is not training properly as this is the first model in TensorFlow I have run. Here is my code: https://pastebin.com/9hJKyVgW